# Why doesn't my javascript function swap pi id html contents as written?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The `p id="demo"` contents don't switch when I click the button on my testing & hosted environ. not sure why? I think the code is correct?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myWhen() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "when-Estimated time to complete is Fall 2016.";
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul>
        <li><button onclick="myWhen()"><p>WHEN?</p></button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="textbox">
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph Written<br>Another line here</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/q8on953b/. Check the console for errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: thank you! but i am totally stumped as i have confirmed and checked....are u saying that the other code i have on the page might be "interfering" with this code snippet?

Comment: thanks--problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

your code is right & it's working.
Check your results here..

```js
function myWhen() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "when-Estimated time to complete is Fall 2016.";
        }
```

```html
<ul>
        <li><button onclick="myWhen()"><p>WHEN?</p></button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="textbox">
        <p id="demo">A Paragraph Written<br>Another line here</p>
    </div>
```